# Alternative quantity selection - cognitive load & space problem

Tags: buttons, e-commerce, shopping-cart, progressive-disclosure, cognitive-load

I am working on a product where users are ordering rather large quantities. Or even better said: The amount that people buy varies wildly. Some order a lot, some a bit less. We are aiming at adding two more options.

Currently we have free range selection of quantity with either input field or plus and minus buttons. But since users select pretty well defined quantities (a full box or a full van!), we want to give those options to add that quantity directly.

***What we currently have***
[image: Current product module]

***Experiments***
I tried adding the buttons for box and van next to it, but it clutters things up a lot, and I find it hard to find the correct solution. Something else I tried is below, which is adding a kebab for alternative actions. And letting an panel slide-in with the box and van buttons.

[image]

However, seeing the numbers of people ordering boxes and vans they both seem too much of a primary action to simply but them behind something.

Do you possibly see any other routes that I could take this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: for example, the van quantity represent an exact quantity?

Comment: Yes @AlejandroVeltri, the van and box are both set quantities for a product. So a full van of product Y will be for example a precise quantity of 920.

Comment: how many predefined quantities are there approximately?

Comment: Three. You can order a box, a full van or a self-defined amount.

Comment: Answer below :). Hope it helps!

Comment: btw, do you also need to support several boxes (or any predifined ammount)? In first place why the user would care if the amount they ask is related with the size of a box or a van? What´s the reason behind that? For example if each box has 30 products, and the client request 90 items, why they would care if that represents 3 boxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if customers use to enter large and diverse quantities, the +/- buttons probably won´t be of much help.

You could keep the normal input and a dropdown where each option specifies the quantity that it represents (mockup). This will also work if more predefined units are added in the future.

The only label I'm not sure about on my mockup is the "predefined one", maybe you could use "custom" to represent the default state (users entering a custom one). See the last mockup for this version.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdr4rK.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, will try to work this one out. Accepted your anser for now.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a dropdown/radio button group after the amount so the person can enter the quantity in numbers and then select how many of what (ie x items/vans/boxes)

Comment: That is one smart possible direction. Somewhat scared though that we get rid of the current conceptual model of a quantity field that always represents the total amount of products bought. Will try out this one. Thanks @Yitzih

Comment: Alejandro posted a similar answer as yours, so consider yours accepted as well!